# Ошибка кодировки

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, utf-8

При создании записи в БД через crud-приложение java кириллические символы в таблице юзеров (crud по юзерам) и в БД (в MySQLWorkbench) отображаются приблизительно так: "???? ??? ????? ?? ?????", в разных вариациях.

Я сделал предположение, что ошибка возникает при записи в БД через hibernate, насколько это точное предположение, не знаю :(

Кодировка БД:

```
Default collation: utf8_general_ci
Default charset: utf8
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
           version="3.0">

    <display-name>CRUD</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncodin</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

index.jsp:

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: promoscow
  Date: 20.06.17
  Time: 21:32
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="from" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>USERS</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tg {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-spacing: 0;
            border-color: #ccc;
        }

        .tg td {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 10px 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            overflow: hidden;
            word-break: normal;
            border-color: #ccc;
            color: #333;
            background-color: #fff;
        }

        .tg th {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-weight: lighter;
            padding: 10px 5px;
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 1px;
            overflow: hidden;
            word-break: normal;
            border-color: #ccc;
            color: #333;
            background-color: #f0f0f0;
        }

        .tg .tg-4eph {
            background-color: #f9f9f9
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table><br/><br/><br/></table>
<h1><center>USERS</center></h1>

<c:if test="${!empty listUsers}">
    <table class="tg" width="90%" align="center">
        <tr>
            <th width=10%>ID</th>
            <th width=30%>User name</th>
            <th width=10%>Age</th>
            <th width=10%>isAdmin</th>
            <th width=20%>Date of registration</th>
            <th width=10%>Edit</th>
            <th width=10%>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${listUsers}" var="user">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">${user.id}</td>
                <td>${user.name}</td>
                <td>${user.age}</td>
                <td>${user.admin}</td>
                <td>${user.createdDate}</td>
                <td align="center"><a href="<c:url value='/edit/${user.id}'/>">Edit</a></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="<c:url value='/remove/${user.id}'/>">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${empty listUsers}"><center>List of users is empty.</center></c:if>
<br>
<h2><center>Add new user</center></h2>
<c:url var="addAction" value="/users/add" />
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="user">
        <table align="center">
            <c:if test="${!empty user.name}">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form:label path="id">
                            <spring:message text="ID"/>
                        </form:label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <form:input path="id" readonly="true" size="8" disabled="true"/>
                        <form:hidden path="id"/>
                    </td>
            </c:if>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="name">
                        <spring:message text="Name"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="name"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="age">
                        <spring:message text="Age"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:input path="age"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:label path="admin">
                        <spring:message text="Admin?"/>
                    </form:label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form:radiobutton path="admin" value="1" label="Yes" />
                    <form:radiobutton path="admin" value="0" label="No" />
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <c:if test="${!empty user.name}">
                        <input type="submit"
                               value="<spring:message text="Edit user data"/>"/>
                    </c:if>
                    <c:if test="${empty user.name}">
                        <input type="submit"
                               value="<spring:message text="Add user"/>"/>
                    </c:if>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.xpendence.javarushtest"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Database Information -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="root"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>ru.xpendence.javarushtest.model.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!--BookDao and BookService beans-->
    <bean id="userDao" class="ru.xpendence.javarushtest.dao.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="userService" class="ru.xpendence.javarushtest.service.UserServiceImpl">
        <property name="userDao" ref="userDao"/>
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.xpendence.javarushtest"/>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

</beans>
```

Comment: Внуть хтмл тега `head` добавьте `<meta charset="UTF-8">` и дополните вопрос настройками подключения к БД.

Comment: Добавил mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml, если Вы про него (настройки). Добавление meta в head проблему не решило.

Comment: В `hibernateProperties` добавьте еще `<prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</prop>`

Comment: К сожалению, не сработало.

Comment: могу только порекомендовать следующее:1. перед сохранением в БД вывести часть данных в консоль, и также после получения из БД (чтоб понять, что виновата БД).  2. проверить в БД у `schema` кодировку, а также в таблицах кодировку каждой текстовой колонки, `table collation` , `column collation`, везде должно стоять `utf8_general_ci`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После многочисленных попыток наладить дело помогло изменение ссылки к БД на

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
```

Answer (score -1):

Насколько я помню MySQL WorkBench не умеет показывать текст в кодировке UTF-8 и все показывает в кодировке чуть ли не Latin1 - поэтому вы и видите символы `????`

Возможно в новых версиях все изменили.

Так что проблема в WB, но не в кодировке/collation ваших таблиц

Comment: Если проблема в WB, то в листинге в браузере должно показывать нормально, нет?

Comment: в браузере должно нормально показывать, если браузер настроен на кодировку UTF-8